# jqueryUi autocomplete combobox going up instead of down

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way to show the combobox ending instead of starting in the autocomplete form if the autocomplete is near the bottom of a page (pageview).

The problem with this widget is that if it's near the bottom, the combobox will not be visible; as it's going down